# Can't display the output result in browser returned from htmlentities() function in php

Tags: php, function, reference

I tried to display the output returned from htmlentities() function. But, it display nothing in browser. Here is my code..

```
$advertisement = "Coffee at 'Cafè Française' costs $2.25.";
echo htmlentities($advertisement);
```

The result should like this:

**Coffee at 'Cafè Française' costs $2.25.**

But, there is nothing displaying in browser.

When I assign the output in a variable, it's value is not NULL. The testing code is:

```
$temp = htmlentities($advertisement);
if($temp === NULL)
    echo "Null";
else
    echo "Not null";
```

Then, the result is "Not null";

I also try this code as testing:

```
$str = "A 'quote' is `<b>`bold`</b>`";

//Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);
```

But, the output in browser is not I expected. I mean in browser it's not replaced `<b>` with `&lt;b&gt;`

What am I missing? Do I need to change any setting in php.ini file?

Comment: do it without htmlentities it is used to change html special character is printables such as < as $lt;

Comment: Read http://kunststube.net/escapism.

Answer (score 0):

That is what htmlentities is supposed to do. Just echo the string out and it should implement the HTML automatically.

```
$str = "A quote is <b>bold</b>";
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the default UTF-8 encoding and the French language. You'll have to change the encoding to ISO-8859-15 for the code, avec Française, to work:

```
$advertisement = "Coffee at 'Cafè Française' costs $2.25.";
echo htmlentities($advertisement, ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-15");
```

When you view it in a browser, it will remain unchanged. This is what htmlentities is meant to do. If you right click the browser and look at the source, you will see the expected conversion:

```
Coffee at &#039;Caf&egrave; Fran&ccedil;aise&#039; costs $2.25.
```